# How to launch application after installation (WIX toolset v4)

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix4

This question is answered [here](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install/) for WIX toolset v3 but I don't seem to find a lead to do the same on WIX v4. There is [this link](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/wixui/) in the official documentation making reference to WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT allowing to show a checkbox at the end which could be used to launch the application but the idea is not further developed.

BTW, if I try the solution for V3 I get an error in the publish tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WIX toolset v4 there are a few changes.
Namely:

- Within the `<Publish>` element the condition goes from being part of the text as a specific attribute called `Condition`
- Within the `<CustomAction>` element the `BinaryKey` is replaced with `BinaryRef`

The final authoring would be as follows:

```
<UI Id="UI">
    <!-- Creates a basic UI for the installer -->
    <ui:WixUI Id="WixUI_Minimal" />

    <!-- Shows launch application on last screen -->
    <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
        Control="Finish"
        Event="DoAction"
        Value="LaunchApplication"
        Condition="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed"/>
</UI>

<!-- Checkbox checked by default -->
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1"/>

<!-- Checkbox text message -->
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="!(loc.LaunchOnExit)"/>

<!-- Set our executable (its ID) as custom action target -->
<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#MYEXECUTABLES_ID]"/>

<!-- Run custom action -->
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication"
    BinaryRef="Wix4UtilCA_$(sys.BUILDARCHSHORT)"
    DllEntry="WixShellExec"
    Impersonate="yes" />
```

Where `MYEXECUTABLES_ID` is defined when defining the component:

```
<Component Id="COMPONENT_ID" Guid="PUT-GUID-HERE">
    <File Id="MYEXECUTABLES_ID" Source="MySourceFiles\MyApplication.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
</Component>
```

If the component is harvested, the file id prevails.